# How do I limit the number of remote desktop connections per user (Win 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, user-management

When I remote desktop into my server I would like to be connected to an existing session or be prevented from connecting as that user so I don't have multiple unknown sessions floating around.

I have set inactive session to expire after 30 minutes but I am not willing to end session on disconnect.

Is there a way to specify a limit per user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Server 2008 R2, you can go to "Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration" (called Terminal Server Configuration on older versions of Windows) and you can set the 'Restrict each user to a single session'. This is the only limit that I know of in Terminal Services/RDP.

Comment: Of course I had already figured this out in the past 18 months.  Thanks for reminding me about the question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that this isn't possible.  Most of the time you will connect with the existing session if you are the same user, although I have not figured out the pattern of when you don't.

Comment: There is a way to specify a limit, its not configurable, its just restrict to single session, as stated by @KJ-SRS.